# Unable to compile C++20 code using g++ 9.3.0

Tags: g++

I am trying to use compile C++20 code using g++ 9.3.0 using the flags mentioned in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) but I am running into an error

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

void span_test() {
    constexpr int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto s = std::span{a};

    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl;
} 

int main() {
    span_test();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that this is not the latest version of g++ that works with C++20. I need to create shared object files with the g++ 9.3.0 since I am restricted by Xcelium.

```bash
g++ -c -std=c++2a -fPIC libdpi.cpp -o libdpi.o
```

```bash
libdpi.cpp:2:10: fatal error: span: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <span>
      |          ^~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: See also the library status at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html . In short, your GCC version is too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g++ 9.3.0 does not support span, g++ 10 or above supports span.

see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20.